# Gene Expression won't work because " arguments imply differing number of rows"

Tags: r

I'm using the ALL dataset from Bioconductor.  My task is to convert the “BT” attribute to categorical variables with just two levels, “B” and “T” and then test all genes for significant association with B/T disease subtype using ANOVA and then plot the p-values.

As a solution I performed the following:

```
> bcell = grep("^B", as.factor(ALL$BT))
> tcell = grep("^T", as.factor(ALL$BT))
```

Then I adapted a snippet of code that I've also used for age:

```
> anova.lm.bcell <- function(x) {
+ df.tmp <-data.frame(Expr=x,bcell)
+ anova(lm(bcell~Expr,df.tmp)) ["Expr", "Pr(>F)"]
+ }
```

But when I assess B-cell's role (from BT) in gene expression with the code below I get the awful "differing number of rows" message!

```
p.bcell <- apply(exprs(ALL), 1, anova.lm.bcell)

 Error in data.frame(Expr = x, bcell) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 128, 95
```

This makes perfect sense, I have 95 "B" cells and 33 "T" cells but I cannot develop a script that will work?

Comment: **You should absolutely *not* use ANOVA to perform a differential gene expression analysis of RNA-seq/microarray data.** Much more sophisticated methods exist, e.g. `DESeq2`, `limma`, `edgeR`, `baySeq` (all of which are available as Bioconductor packages). A critical part of these optimised methods is the robust estimation of the mean-variance relationship from data for *all* genes, which is then used in the characterisation of the underlying probability distribution when modelling the mean expression per gene. In an ANOVA (+ post-hoc test) you are simply performing >20k *individual* tests.

Comment: I understand Maurits and thank you for always offering help (seriously).  I'm not sure why I'm being asked to perform it this way.  I do plan to learn much more about the limma package, starting with JHU's 4-week course that is online.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome @Oars; perhaps this is meant as a statistical exercise? I've used ANOVA in this context to demonstrate how poorly & unreliably ANOVA identifies differentially expressed genes in comparison to e.g. `limma` and `DESeq2`. Anyway, good luck with the course. BTW, the `limma` vignette is very comprehensive and provides you with a lot of (statistics) background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you're choosing `grep()` over `grepl()`?

If you use `grepl()` and wrap it in a call to `as.integer()`, then you'll have an integer vector that will be the same length as your original data.frame.

```
bcell = as.integer(grepl("^B", as.factor(ALL$BT)))
tcell = as.integer(grepl("^T", as.factor(ALL$BT)))

anova.lm.bcell <- function(x) {
    df.tmp <-data.frame(Expr=x,bcell=bcell)
    anova(lm(bcell~Expr,df.tmp)) ["Expr", "Pr(>F)"]
}

p.bcell <- apply(exprs(ALL), 1, anova.lm.bcell)
```

The value of `bcell` will be `1` when `ALL$BT` begins with a "B" and `0` otherwise. Is a simple 1/0 flag for your `bcell` and `tcell` vector sufficient for your use-case?

Comment: Thank you Taylor, this changes the TRUE/FALSE results to 0 1 which I think is helpful.